# How to use alias in KnexJS raw query

Tags: knex.js

I have an issue using the alias in KnexJS raw query.

The following part works If I run the whole query without the alias.

- .count(db.raw(`case when finish_time is not null then '1' else 'null' end)

The following part with the alias doesn't work

- .count(db.raw(`(case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end) as count_finished`))

And here is the whole query that I want to run.

```
.table("task_history")
.count(db.raw("distinct date"))
.where('store_id', request.params.storeid)
.where('date', '>', function() {
  this.select('date')
    .from(function() {
      this.select('date')
        .table("task_history")
        .first()
        .count('* as count_all')
        .count(db.raw(`(case when
          finish_time is not null
          then 1 else null
          end) as count_finished`))
        .where('store_id', request.params.storeid)
        .groupBy('date')
        .orderBy('count_finished', 'asc')
        .orderBy('date', 'desc')
        .as('get_max_date')
    })
});
```

Does anyone know why it is happening?

[UPDATE]: Here is my solution.

```
.select( db.raw("count(case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end) as count_finished"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: paste the raw sql you want.

Comment: Hi Fazal Rasel, I have put the whole query. Basically, the query works fine when I don't use "as" in the following query:

.count(db.raw((case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end) as count_finished)), but I still want to use the alias there. Any idea?

Comment: I guess you are having issue with order by "`count_finished`". As you are using "`count_finished`" on where cause on a sub_query, you can don't order by this way.

Comment: Here is the generated sql "select count(distinct date) from `task_history` where `store_id` = ? and `date` > (select `date` from (select `date`, count(*) as `count_all`, count((case when\n          finish
_time is not null\n          then 1 else null\n          end) as count_finished) from `task_history` where `store_id` = ? group by `date` order by `count_finished` asc, `date` desc limi
t ?) as `get_max_date`)"

Comment: Thank you Fazal Rasel. 
If I don't use "as" there, then KnexJS will create an alias called "count" automatically, and then I could use that "count" in order by such as ".orderBy('count', 'asc')". It worked fine , but I want to use "count_finished" instead of "count"

I was wondering why I can set the alias explicitly instead of using the one by Knex.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just need to do it like this:

```
.select(knex.raw('count(distinct ??) as bar',  ['columnName']))
```

Example: https://runkit.com/embed/tt0q08glnjgn

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I've already figured it out like what you wrote above. 
Here is my solution - .select( db.raw("count(case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end) as count_finished"))